# Object snaps upwards when trying to link with armature

Tags: armature, bones, snapping

I'm trying to link an armature I made for a model to a different model (with a very similar shape), but when I try to link them together (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> -> Set Parent to Bone) the model snaps upward. I thought this might be because the 3D cursor isn't set to the right place so I checked and gave it another try but that didn't seem to work either.

[image]

I'm hoping this image describes it well enough. The moment I select Set Parent to Bone, it immediately snaps up. If I could get help that would be really great, thanks!!

EDIT:
thanks for the suggestions. i tried both resetting the armature to its original position and 'Set parent to -> Armature Deform -> With Automatic Weights/With Empty Groups' but the snapping still seems to be happening.
i've added the .blend file below if that helps. i apologise if it's a very noob-y issue as i'm quite new to blender and i've been asking a lot of novice questions.
[image]
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have moved your armature up/down in pose mode. You can check this using <kbd>tab</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> on your armature.
The position of your armature has to be the same in object/edit mode and pose mode, and matching your mesh, before you apply it.

To fix this, select all bones with <kbd>A</kbd> in pose mode, then you can reset position with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, scale with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and rotation with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. This makes the pose back to "rest position" wich is the same as edit/object mode pose. Then you can move your armature (object mode) or your mesh to match them.

EDIT:
Your problem is that your mesh and armature are parented, but as objects. You can fix this problem adding an armature modifier to your **mesh** and selecting your armature as object. Be sure to check vertex groups (default) as they have been created earlier (and working well).
[image: modifier]

You can also fix the problem using the 1st part of this answer after selecting your mesh and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to clear parenting. Then you can make things cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be setting the parent to the bone. You should be setting "Set parent to -> Armature Deform -> With Automatic Weights" or "With Empty Groups" depending on your needs.